# Why do I now have to enter username and password when connecting from iPhone to the ad-hoc wireless network created on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, iphone, adhoc

I'm having problem connecting to ad-hoc I created in ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

My office have a restricted (and very slow) Wifi which isnt much of any use.

So I figured I could create an ad-hoc in my laptop connected via cable to enjoy the fast and unrestricted connection from my iPhone. And it worked well until 2 weeks ago.

I believe one of the Ubuntu updates (or even iOS update, not sure) affected somehow this connection. 
From 2 weeks until now, whenever I try to connect my ad-hoc (WEP 40/128bit Key) from my iPhone I am prompted to inform a username and a password.

I have tried all kind of possible usernames and none have worked. I don't even know which password is to be used... Is it my Ubuntu users pass? The pass I configured the connection with?

Once again, I can't tell if the problem is the Ubuntu or the iOS.. But I can't find any solution and figured someone out here would be going through the same (or gone through).

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering the question, but I can't post comment yet. Sorry for that.

Do you know that WEP is completely broken? You'd better not encrypt anything: it will be as efficient to protect you and you won't have any user/password problem.

You can try to set up a WPA ad-hoc connection using:

```
ap_scan=2
network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    mode=1
    freq=2412
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    psk="passwd"
}
```

and launch it using

```
wpa_supplicant -cfile.conf -iwlan0 -Dwext
```

You can also try to get connection from USB. I did that months ago with my android phone (internet connection on the laptop --> mobile phone)

Comment: I didn't know WEP is completely broken. I know i can share my 3G to the computer from my iPhone, but I don't think I can do it the other way around.

Maybe with tweak or app from Cydia?